curl: (77) error setting certificate verify locations on Catalina
I'm attempting to install Python and AWS tools via curl and keep getting this error:
curl: (77) error setting certificate verify locations:
CAfile: /usr/local/php5/ssl/cert.pem
CApath: none

I have seen other answers that seem vaguely related to this but most of them are 10 years old or older and the solutions seem convoluted so I thought I would see if there's a current approach to this that's more straightforward.
Until today I never had an issue with this. I have installed various other packages without difficulty. I'm not a terminal-level programmer, I just follow instructions, copy/paste, etc. I appreciate any assistance that might be provided.
